# What does this wind turbine do?

Tags: props, legends-of-the-fall

In the movie, ***Legends of the Fall***, Colonel William Ludlow leaves the US army and starts living as a rancher in Montata. We can see a wind turbine in the background, what does it do given the story starts around 1910s?

[image]

Comment: What difference does it make for the windmill function that the story is in 1910?

Comment: @Luciano - OP may be unaware that windmills have been used for purposes other than electricity generation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wind has been used for hundreds of years for pumping water, grinding grain or providing power to drive a sawmill for cutting wood.

Even by 1910 it was definitely possible that this was an electricity generator ([source](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/wind/history-of-wind-power.php)) too. Electric lighting was available from the 1870s.

Given the size of the blades here, it doesn't seem like this would provide enough power for grinding grain or a sawmill, but it seems reasonable to me that it might either pump water or generate electricity. It might pump water from a stream or well for animals or the farmhouse.

Comment: https://www.napersettlement.org/520/Windmill

Comment: https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/windmills-water-pumping-museum-indiana

Comment: https://www.nps.gov/articles/windmills.htm